# Configuring Cobertura with Ant

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, cobertura

I'm trying to get Cobertura working for my project's Ant build, and all I have to work with are the documentation/FAQs and a sample `build.xml` that uses cobertura, but apparently never worked (ha!).

- I see in the Cobertura `taskdef` a resource called `tasks.properties` - what is this file and where is it located on my machine (I couldn't find it anywhere inside my Eclipse home)?
- Where am I supposed to install the `cobertura.jar` to, so that Ant knows how to reference it directly (instead of an absolute path)?

Thanks in advance for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tasks.properties is bundled inside the cobertura JAR file; you can view it like so on a UNIX-like system:

```
jar xf cobertura.jar tasks.properties; cat tasks.properties
```

You could put cobertura.jar in the lib subdirectory of your local Ant installation if you want to it always be available, but IMO it's better to store it in a separate location and add it to your classpath explicitly in your build file.  This prevents unwanted classes from being loaded in other builds.